# How can I display my ATL control in CView

Tags: mfc, activex, atl, cview

I have made an ATL control (ActiveX) and I can display it easily in MFC `CDialog`. Now I need to display it in `CView` of MFC single document project by using the code (just like the picture below).
Don't use `CForm` because my customer don't need it. They need exactly Control display in `CView` by code.

Are there any tutorial or suggestion for this task?

[image]

Comment: Rather the contrary. If you want a view that hosts an ActiveX control, then a `CFormView` is exactly what you need. Yes, `CFormView` is normal code, so you *could* write your own form type that does the same things, but avoiding such things is exactly why you use a framework.

Answer (score 0):

The MFC CView class doesn't directly support hosting of Win32 or ActiveX controls on its surface. That functionality is built into the CFormView class. If you want to readily host controls on your view, you should be using [CFormView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cformview-class?view=msvc-170#remarks).